# url not showing because of middleware file

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls, django-middleware

Im trying to access my index view but i' m automatically redirected to show_login view , i think that the problem comes from my custom middleware file

here is the main view:

```
def indexmain(request):
    return render(request, "main_template/index.html")
```

Urls :

```
     path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/',include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('', views.ShowLoginPage, name="show_login"),
    path('indexmain', views.indexmain,name="index"),
    path('get_user_details', views.GetUserDetails),
    path('logout_user', views.logout_user,name="logout"),
    path('doLogin',views.doLogin,name="do_login"),
```

**here is my custom Middleware file:**

```
    from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin


class LoginCheckMiddleWare(MiddlewareMixin):

    def process_view(self,request,view_func,view_args,view_kwargs):
        modulename=view_func.__module__
        print(modulename)
        user=request.user
        if user.is_authenticated:
            if user.user_type == "1":
                if modulename == "gestion.HodViews":
                    pass
                elif modulename == "gestion.views" or modulename == "django.views.static":
                    pass
                elif modulename == "django.contrib.auth.views" or modulename =="django.contrib.admin.sites":
                    pass
                else:
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("admin_home"))
            elif user.user_type == "2":
                if modulename == "gestion.StaffViews" or modulename == "gestion.EditResultVIewClass":
                    pass
                elif modulename == "student_management_app.views" or modulename == "django.views.static":
                    pass
                else:
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("staff_home"))

            else:
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("show_login"))

        else:
            if request.path == reverse("index") or request.path == reverse("show_login") or request.path == reverse("do_login") or modulename == "django.contrib.auth.views" or modulename =="django.contrib.admin.sites" :
                pass
            else:
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("show_login"))
```

Answer (score 0):

try removing last else part and it will work

```
else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("show_login"))
```